# How to give public access for some specific file in GCS bucket during upload (json api)?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How to give public access for some specific file in GCS bucket during upload using (json api)?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation is here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert), just include an optional query parameter

```
"predefinedAcl": "publicRead"
```